# MySQL - Hold a record for while and release it if user failed to change the state

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I'm working on a scenario which thousands of users can edit a text file, they have limited time to make their updations. while one user is accessing a file I want to restrict the other users to access it, by setting `true` for "`isAccessing`" column in my SQL table. What if there is a connection loss on the client side. So, they will fail to update the status of the record "`isAccessing`" to "`false`".  can I have a method in my database if the user is failed to update the status of the record?. So the database will automatically change the state to `false`.

Please help me with some ideas.

Comment: You can save time of `isAccessing`. By cron check this time for timeout and set `false` when needed.

Comment: There are open source tools that provide collaborative real-time editing. Consider reading their source code and seeing how they handle this. (Many of them manage to do it without locking the entire file.)

Comment: @Chris where is the source code :(

Comment: @Sathish, finding or recommending off-site resources is off-topic (see the [help/on-topic]). But I gave you a search term in my previous comment. Search the web for "open source real time collaborative editor" and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for quoting this time "open source real time collaborative editor" @Chris  :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing isAccessing with a timestamp column (i.e. accessingUntilTime), which will hold the deadline until the user can edit the post.

For example, assuming now is TIME, you can add TIME + X to that column as its value for this new post. Assuming the user timed out and didn't edit, the time has passed after X and you can check the condition to see if it's true.

Comment: Good idea though!, Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)